# Decorator objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain how the getDecorator and 
tree.BlueBalls functions work? How do these function modify the tree object?

```
var tree = {};
tree.decorate = function() {
  alert('Make sure the tree won\'t fall');
};

tree.getDecorator = function(deco){
  tree[deco].prototype = this;
  return new tree[deco];

};

tree.BlueBalls = function() {
  this.decorate = function() {
    this.BlueBalls.prototype.decorate();
    alert('Add blue balls');
  }
};


tree = tree.getDecorator('BlueBalls');
tree.decorate()
```

Comment: what does `this.BlueBalls.prototype.decorate();` do?

Answer (score 0):

The decorator function creates a new object (which is essentially a new property for the tree object) `Blueballs` which has tree as its prototype and returns it.

Now if you call the newly created object, it will first invoke its prototype's `decorate` function (`this.BlueBalls.prototype.decorate()`) and then its own `decorate` function, resulting in the two alerts 'Make sure the tree won\'t fall' and 'Add blue balls'.

For those who are not familiar with the design pattern: The [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) essentially adds behavior to an existing object by creating a "wrapper", so it does not affect the behavior of the original object.